# Add a rank/order column that will not reset when encountering a lower number

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to add an 'order' column that will look at the 'week' column and for every time the week column changes, regardless if it increases/decreases, the order number will be +1.

original_df

```
     Col1     week
1     A        42
2     A        42
3     A        45
4     A        46
5     A        3
6     A        3
7     A        8
```

Desired DF

```
     Col1     week     order
1     A        42        1
2     A        42        1
3     A        45        2
4     A        46        3
5     A        3         4
6     A        3         4         
7     A        8         5
```

Comment: assume  row 7 has `week=42` instead of `8` (i.e. it repeats the value of row 1 and 2), what is the value of `order` you want to be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `diff` and `cumsum`:

```
df["order"] = df["week"].diff().ne(0).cumsum()

print (df)

  Col1  week  order
1    A    42      1
2    A    42      1
3    A    45      2
4    A    46      3
5    A     3      4
6    A     4      5
7    A     8      6
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `ne` with `cumsum`:

```
df.week.ne(df.week.shift(1)).cumsum()
```